# how to know if JDialog is closed or not?

Tags: java, jdialog

I have used a JDialog to display a form ( I could have used JFrame, but I have my reasons). There is an event in my application that will cause a function to generate and display the said JDialog. Now, I want to know if the user has closed that JDialog. How do I find this out?

**P.S.** My defaultCloseOperation is JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register a window listener on the dialog, and implement the `windowClosed` method, see [The Java Tutorial on Window Listeners](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html)